# ddply + summarize for repeating same statistical function across large number of columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns, plyr, idioms, split-apply-combine

Ok, second R question in quick succession.

My data:

```
           Timestamp    St_01  St_02 ...
1 2008-02-08 00:00:00  26.020 25.840 ...
2 2008-02-08 00:10:00  25.985 25.790 ...
3 2008-02-08 00:20:00  25.930 25.765 ...
4 2008-02-08 00:30:00  25.925 25.730 ...
5 2008-02-08 00:40:00  25.975 25.695 ...
...
```

Basically normally I would use a combination of `ddply` and `summarize` to calculate ensembles (e.g. mean for every hour across the whole year).

In the case above, I would  create a category, e.g. hour (e.g. `strptime(data$Timestamp,"%H") -> data$hour` and then use that category in `ddply`, like `ddply(data,"hour", summarize, St_01=mean(St_01), St_02=mean(St_02)...)` to average by category across each of the columns.

but here is where it gets sticky. I have more than 40 columns to deal with and I'm not prepared to type them all one by one as parameters to the `summarize` function. I used to write a loop in shell to generate this code but that's not how programmers solve problems is it?

So pray tell, does anyone have a better way of achieving the same result but with less keystrokes?

Comment: Or reshape the `St` variables long then use your favorite aggregation functions `by`, `aggregate`, `ddply` to combine by `c(hour,index)`, where `index` is the variable created in the reshape.

Comment: easy points for ya :-)

Comment: lol thanks! hahaha. faith in humanity restored.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `numcolwise()` to run a summary over all numeric columns.

Here is an example using `iris`:

```
ddply(iris, .(Species), numcolwise(mean))
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

---

Similarly, there is `catcolwise()` to summarise over all categorical columns.

See `?numcolwise` for more help and examples.

---

**EDIT**

An alternative approach is to use `reshape2` (proposed by @gsk3).  This has more keystrokes in this example, but gives you enormous flexibility:

library(reshape2)

```
miris <- melt(iris, id.vars="Species")
x <- ddply(miris, .(Species, variable), summarize, mean=mean(value))

dcast(x, Species~variable, value.var="mean")
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

Comment: one thing. how does it work with summarize? cos i need to summarize categorically within each column too.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Using `colwise` or family usually means you don't need to use `summarize`. Can you please expand on your question?

Comment: @R-L it's either-or, two different approaches. Both have their merits. The `melt` one is neat if you're going to do a large amount of statistical calculations on each column, and want to peek at intermediate results.

Answer (score 7):

You can even simplify the second approach proposed by Andrie by omitting the ddply call completely. Just specify `mean` as the aggregation function in the dcast call:

```
library(reshape2)
miris <- melt(iris, id.vars="Species")
dcast(miris, Species ~ variable, mean)

     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

The same result can also be calculated very fast using the `data.table` package. The `.SD` variable in the j expression is a special data.table variable containing the subset of data for each group, excluding all columns used in `by`.

```
library(data.table)
dt_iris <- as.data.table(iris)
dt_iris[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = Species]

     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1:     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
2: versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
3:  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

Yet another option would be the new version 0.2 of Hadley's `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(iris, Species) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))

Source: local data frame [3 x 5]

     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```