# Blend of na.omit and na.pass using aggregate?

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr, summary

I have a data set containing product prototype test data. Not all tests were run on all lots, and not all tests were executed with the same sample sizes. To illustrate, consider this case:

```
> test <- data.frame(name = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4),
  var1 = rep(c(1:3, NA), 3),
  var2 = 1:12,
  var3 = c(rep(NA, 4), 1:8))

> test
   name var1 var2 var3
1     A    1    1   NA
2     A    2    2   NA
3     A    3    3   NA
4     A   NA    4   NA
5     B    1    5    1
6     B    2    6    2
7     B    3    7    3
8     B   NA    8    4
9     C    1    9    5
10    C    2   10    6
11    C    3   11    7
12    C   NA   12    8
```

In the past, I've only had to deal with cases of mis-matched repetitions, which has been easy with `aggregate(cbind(var1, var2) ~ name, test, FUN = mean, na.action = na.omit)` (or the default setting). I'll get averages for each lot over three values for `var1` and over four values for `var2`.

Unfortunately, this will leave me with a dataset completely missing lot `A` in this case:

```
 aggregate(cbind(var1, var2, var3) ~ name, test, FUN = mean, na.action = na.omit)
  name var1 var2 var3
1    B    2    6    2
2    C    2   10    6
```

If I use `na.pass`, however, I also don't get what I want:

```
 aggregate(cbind(var1, var2, var3) ~ name, test, FUN = mean, na.action = na.pass)
  name var1 var2 var3
1    A   NA  2.5   NA
2    B   NA  6.5  2.5
3    C   NA 10.5  6.5
```

Now I lose the good data I had in `var1` since it contained instances of `NA`.

What I'd like is:

- `NA` as the output of `mean()` if *all* unique combinations of `varN` ~ `name` are `NA`s
- Output of `mean()` if there are one or more actual values for `varN` ~ `name`

I'm guessing this is pretty simple, but I just don't know how. Do I need to use `ddply` for something like this? If so... the reason I tend to avoid it is that I end up writing really long equivalents to `aggregate()` like so:

```
ddply(test, .(name), summarise,
  var1 = mean(var1, na.rm = T),
  var2 = mean(var2, na.rm = T),
  var3 = mean(var3, na.rm = T))
```

Yeah... so the result of that apparently does what I want. I'll leave the question anyway in case there's 1) a way to do this with `aggregate()` or 2) shorter syntax for `ddply`.

Comment: Re-stumbled on one answer re. `ddply` [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787640/r-ddply-summarize-with-large-number-of-columns). Basically, melt the data frame, apply `mean()` based on combinations of the variable of interest and the former column name, then cast it back to the original shape. Any others?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pass *both* `na.action=na.pass` and `na.rm=TRUE` to `aggregate`. The former tells `aggregate` not to delete rows where NAs exist; and the latter tells `mean` to ignore them.

```
aggregate(cbind(var1, var2, var3) ~ name, test, mean,
          na.action=na.pass, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Awesome, and I had no idea that was possible.

Comment: @HongOoi This worked great. Just something to note, this will replace the NAs with zeros depending on which function you choose. This is most likely not the final result you want so just be sure to follow up with something like `df[df == 0] <- NA`. If you have real zeros in your df that you don't want removed, then combine the code above with `is.na(df)`

Comment: heads up this returns `NaN`, rather than `NA` for name `A`, `var3`