# Collapsing rows where some are all NA, others are disjoint with some NAs

Tags: r, aggregate, na

I have a simple dataframe as such:

```
ID    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
1     NA      NA      NA      NA  
1     5       10      NA      NA
1     NA      NA      15      20
2     NA      NA      NA      NA  
2     25      30      NA      NA
2     NA      NA      35      40
```

And I would like to reformat it as such:

```
ID    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
1     5       10      15      20
2     25      30      35      40
```

(please note: the real data set has thousands of rows and the values are from biological data -- the `NA`s follow no simple pattern, except that the `NA`s are disjoint, and yes there are exactly 3 rows for each `ID`).

**STEP ONE**: get rid of rows that have only `NA` values.

On the surface this looked simple, but I've run across some problems.

`complete.cases(DF)` returns all `FALSE`, so I can't really use this to remove the rows with all `NA`s, as in `DF[complete.cases(DF),]`. This is because all rows contain at least one `NA`.

Since `NA`s want to propagate themselves, other schemes using `is.na` fail for the same reason.

**STEP TWO**: collapse the remaining two rows into one.

Thinking about using something like `aggregate` to pull this off, but there has got to be an easier way than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268814/merge-two-rows-in-one-dataframe), which doesn't work at all.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Is the data always 100% numeric?

Comment: related: [blend of na.omit and na.pass using aggregate in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737174/blend-of-na-omit-and-na-pass-using-aggregate-in-r)

Comment: Is there always exactly one non-NA value per column per group or could there be more?

Comment: More! For better or worse

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

**Edit:** To account for the case in which one column has all `NAs` for a certain `ID`, we need `sum_NA()` function which returns `NA` if all are `NAs`

```
txt <- "ID    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
        1     NA      NA      NA      NA
        1     5       10      NA      NA
        1     NA      NA      15      20
        2     NA      NA      NA      NA
        2     NA      30      NA      NA
        2     NA      NA      35      40"
DF <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)

# original code
DF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))

# `summarise_each()` is deprecated.
# Use `summarise_all()`, `summarise_at()` or `summarise_if()` instead.
# To map `funs` over all variables, use `summarise_all()`
# A tibble: 2 x 5
     ID  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     5    10    15    20
2     2     0    30    35    40

sum_NA <- function(x) {if (all(is.na(x))) x[NA_integer_] else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)}

DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum_NA))

DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(sum_NA))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
     ID  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     5    10    15    20
2     2    NA    30    35    40
```

Comment: I think `summarise_each(funs(na.omit(.)) )` also works

Comment: Yes, but I think that would yield a little dissonant result if any of the columns had more than 2 non-NA observations.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if any column has all `NA`s for a certain `ID`. For example replace `25` by `NA` for `ID = 2` in `Col1`. Whereas `funs(na.omit(.))` will throw error `Error: Column Col1 must be length 1 (a summary value), not 0`

Answer (score 18):

Here's a data table approach that uses `na.omit()` across the columns, grouped by ID.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = ID]
#    ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
# 1:  1    5   10   15   20
# 2:  2   25   30   35   40
```

Comment: `na.omit` is clever. Better than `sum` and will work on non-numeric data. I'm discreetly going to edit...

Comment: This solution doesn't work if any column has all NAs for a certain ID.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a couple of aggregate attempts:

```
aggregate(. ~ ID, data=dat, FUN=na.omit, na.action="na.pass")
#  ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
#1  1    5   10   15   20
#2  2   25   30   35   40
```

Since `aggregate`'s formula interface by default uses `na.omit` on the entire data before doing any grouping, it will delete every row of `dat` as they all contain at least one `NA` value. Try it: `nrow(na.omit(dat))` returns `0`. So in this case, use `na.pass` in `aggregate` and then `na.omit` to skip over the `NA`s that were passed through.

Alternatively, don't use the formula interface and specify the columns to aggregate manually:

```
aggregate(dat[-1], dat[1], FUN=na.omit )
aggregate(dat[c("Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4")], dat["ID"], FUN=na.omit)
#  ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
#1  1    5   10   15   20
#2  2   25   30   35   40
```

Answer (score 8):

Since `dplyr 1.0.0`, you can also do (using the data provided by @Khashaa):

```
df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>%
 summarize(across(everything(), ~ first(na.omit(.))))

     ID  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     5    10    15    20
2     2    NA    30    35    40
```

Answer (score 1):

the simple way is:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(myData[,c('Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4')],function(x)[!is.na(x)]))
```

but if not all columns have the same number of non-`NA` values then you'll need to trim them like so:

```
temp  <-  lapply(myData[,c('Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4')],function(x)x[!is.na(x)])
len  <-  min(sapply(temp,length))
as.data.frame(lapply(temp,`[`,seq(len)))
```