# Create all possible combinations of non-NA values for each group ID

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, na

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036294/collapsing-rows-where-some-are-all-na-others-are-disjoint-with-some-nas) question but with an added twist:

Given the following data frame:

```
txt <- "ID    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
        1     6       10      NA      NA
        1     5       10      NA      NA
        1     NA      10      15      20
        2     17      25      NA      NA
        2     13      25      NA      NA
        2     NA      25      21      34
        2     NA      25      35      40"
DF <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)

DF
  ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1  1    6   10   NA   NA
2  1    5   10   NA   NA
3  1   NA   10   15   20
4  2   17   25   NA   NA
5  2   13   25   NA   NA
6  2   NA   25   21   34
7  2   NA   25   35   40
```

I wish to collapse the rows by group ID (analogous to Col2 in this example), and when more than 1 combination is present per group, to return all combinations, as so:

```
  ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1  1    6   10   15   20
2  1    5   10   15   20
3  2   17   25   21   34
4  2   13   25   21   34
5  2   17   25   35   40
6  2   13   25   35   40
```

**Importantly**, down the road I'll need this to work on non-numerical data. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Row 3 of the original gets collapsed into rows 1-2. Rows 6-7 get collapsed into rows 4-5 with a total of 4 combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouped by 'ID', `fill` other columns, `ungroup` to remove the group attribute and keep the `distinct` rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    fill(everything(), .direction = 'updown') %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)
```

---

Or may also be

```
DF %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., is.na(.), 
           rep(.[!is.na(.)], length.out = sum(is.na(.))))))
```

---

Or based on the comments

```
DF %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(across(where(~ any(is.na(.))), ~ {
        i1 <- is.na(.)
        ind <- which(i1)
        i2 <- !i1
        if(i1[1] == 1) rep(.[i2], each = n()/sum(i2)) else 
               rep(.[i2], length.out = n())
     })) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     ID  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     6    10    15    20
2     1     5    10    15    20
3     2    17    25    21    34
4     2    13    25    21    34
5     2    17    25    35    40
6     2    13    25    35    40
```

Comment: Thanks! These two options give different results. The desired output would be a de-duplicated version of your second response. The first response is missing a collapsed combination of rows 4&7 in the original post

Comment: @Aaron at the time I posted this, I had doubts whether your expected was a typo or not

Comment: understood, the expected is not a typo, thanks!

Comment: @Aaron I have doubt in the Col1 and Col3, in the arrangement of elements.  In Col1, the last 2 elements of ID 2 was missing so , it was 17 13 17 13 repeated, whereas in Col3, first 2 elements are missing, but it was changed to 21 21 35 35 in expected i.e. breaking the order of 21 35

Comment: @Aaron So, my question is more related to the logic behind those difference in filling

Comment: @Aaron i.e. why is 17 13in alternating order whereas 21 35 is repeated order

Comment: @Aaron I updated the post to get the expecetd output, but I am not sure whether the logic you wanted is that

Comment: thanks! for my purposes I don't care about the arrangement of elements so long as all combinations of Col1 and (Col3&Col4) per group ID exist in the output

Comment: @Aaron  The updated solution gives the expected as in your post.  It may need some tweaking when the number of NA elements are different

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` option using `zoo`'s `na.locf` to fill the missing values.

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

setDT(DF)
cols <- grep('Col', names(DF), value = TRUE)
DF[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) fcoalesce(na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE), 
                      na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE))), ID]
unique(DF)

#   ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
#1:  1    6   10   15   20
#2:  1    5   10   15   20
#3:  2   17   25   21   34
#4:  2   13   25   21   34
#5:  2   13   25   35   40
```

Answer (score 2):

[In a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69292138/collapsing-multiple-combinations-of-disjoint-rows-with-na#comment122500855_69292150), the OP pointed out:

> for my purposes I don't care about the arrangement of elements so long
> as all combinations of Col1 and (Col3&Col4) per group ID exist in the
> output

So, if I understand correctly, the question is *not* about collapsing but about creating all possible combinations of *non-NA values* of columns `Col1`, `Col2`, and combined columns (`Col3`, `Col4`) for each `ID` group.

For this, `expand()` and `nesting()` from the [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) package can be used to create the combinations. `na.omit()` removes all rows containing any `NA` *afterwards*:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  expand(Col1, Col2, nesting(Col3, Col4)) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  ungroup()
```

> ```
>      ID  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
> 1     1     5    10    15    20
> 2     1     6    10    15    20
> 3     2    13    25    21    34
> 4     2    13    25    35    40
> 5     2    17    25    21    34
> 6     2    17    25    35    40
> ```

This approach should work well also with non-numerical data.

#### Edit 1

Giving a second thought, I was wondering about the peculiar structure of the input dataset, namely the positions of the `NA`s:

```
DF
```

> ```
>   ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
> 1  1    6   10   NA   NA
> 2  1    5   10   NA   NA
> 3  1   NA   10   15   20
> 4  2   17   25   NA   NA
> 5  2   13   25   NA   NA
> 6  2   NA   25   21   34
> 7  2   NA   25   35   40
> ```

To me, it appears as if `DF` was constructed from three separate subsets, the first one for `Col1`

> ```
>   ID Col1
> 1  1    6
> 2  1    5
> 4  2   17
> 5  2   13
> ```

the second one for `Col2`

> ```
>   ID Col2
> 1  1   10
> 4  2   25
> ```

the third one for `Col3` and `Col4`

> ```
>   ID Col3 Col4
> 3  1   15   20
> 6  2   21   34
> 7  2   35   40
> ```

Based on this observation, here is a different approach which creates all possible combinations of the subsets by a series of merge operations (cartesian joins) of the subsets:

```
library(magrittr) # piping used her to improve readability
list("Col1", "Col2", c("Col3", "Col4")) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) DF[c("ID", x)] %>% na.omit %>% unique) %>% 
  Reduce(merge, .)
```

> ```
>   ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
> 1  1    6   10   15   20
> 2  1    5   10   15   20
> 3  2   17   25   21   34
> 4  2   17   25   35   40
> 5  2   13   25   21   34
> 6  2   13   25   35   40
> ```

Here, `lapply()` creates a list of subsets of the input dataset which is then merged repeatedly using `Reduce()`.

#### Edit 2:

With version 4.1.0, R has gained a simple native forward pipe syntax `|>` and `\()` as a shorthand notation for `function()`. With this, the code of **Edit 1** can be re-written to use only base R (without [magrittr](/questions/tagged/magrittr)):

```
list("Col1", "Col2", c("Col3", "Col4")) |> 
  lapply(\(x) DF[c("ID", x)] |> na.omit() |> unique()) |>
  (\(z) Reduce(merge, z))()
```

Comment: Thanks! You understand correctly, and I edited the question title to make my goal more clear.