# Removing cells with NA values (not columns, no rows, not trimming)

Tags: r, dplyr, na

Say I have the following dataset:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | NA |
| NA | 2 | NA |
| NA | NA | 3 |

and I am trying to get

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

The context for this is that I have such a dataset, where there are values if A is non-empty, B/C are always NA and same goes for B/C. Moreover, the lengths of ABC are not the same.

These are values I then use to calculate overlap coefficient with overlap(x,y) from library(bayestestR). However, if I leave NAs in, the results for overlap(a,a), i.e. the same set, are not 1 but .98 or something along those lines. I am not sure what to do. Please advise! Thanks in advance.

If someone has a tip on how to prompt overlap() to ignore NAs, that would work as well I guess!

I tried

```
df <- data.table(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))])]
df[!result[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, is.na))]]
df[complete.cases(df), ]
```

But it still left NA values, even plenty of rows where all values are NA! This bit of code helps to move up all the non-NA values to the top, but NAs are still there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collapsing rows where some are all NA, others are disjoint with some NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036294/collapsing-rows-where-some-are-all-na-others-are-disjoint-with-some-nas)

Comment: @benson23 I do not have anything like ID given in the response you linked, so nothing to group by? If I group by one of the existing variables like B with NAs in it, the answers in the questions you linked do not seem to make a difference. I've run just them; thanks!

Comment: Having nothing to `group_by` means you can skip that line of code. Continues with `summarize` as suggested in the linked post. I believe the one with `na.omit` works best for you :)

Comment: @benson23 Thanks! I get the following warning, though: "Item 1 has 27 rows but longest item has 49; recycled with remainder."

Comment: What do you mean "the lengths of ABC are not the same"? Dataframes require equal-length vectors, so if there are different numbers of non-NA values per column, then the shorter columns will be recycled with a warning as you discovered -- which almost certainly isn't the result you want. Could you please provide expanded example data and desired output that demonstrates how you want to handle unequal numbers of non-NA values?

Answer (score 0):

A bigger example would help, but try with `dplyr::reframe()` and the already-suggested (by @benson23) `na.omit()`:

```
aux <- tribble(
    ~a, ~b, ~c,
     1, NA, NA,
     1, NA, 31,
    NA,  2, NA,
    NA, NA,  3,
    11, NA, NA)

aux <- reframe(aux, across(everything(), \(x) unique(na.omit(x))))

# A tibble: 2 × 3
    a     b     c
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1     2    31
   11     2     3
```

Comment: But then I get "Error in names(dots)[[i]] : subscript out of bounds"

Answer (score 0):

If your data only have one numeric value in each column, you can use `colSums` with `na.rm = TRUE`. If you want the output in a data.frame, wrap it in `data.frame(as.list(...))`:

```
data.frame(as.list(colSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)))

#   A B C
# 1 1 2 3
```