# Efficient way to calculate sum or return NA if all values are NA

Tags: r, sum, na

During a simulation I created multiple data sets with > 1,000,000 variables. However, some of the values of these variables are `NA` and in some cases even all values are `NA`. Now I'd like to calculate the sum of all values of the variables but want to get `NA` if all values are `NA`.

The problem with the common `sum(x, na.rm=T)` or `sum(na.omit(x))` is, that it returns 0 if all values are `NA`. Thus, I've written my own function that deals with `NA` in the expected way:

```
sumna <- function(x) {
  sumna <- NULL
  return(ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, sum(na.omit(x))))
}
```

However, that implementation is rather slow.

Thus, I'm looking for an implementation or pre-implemented function that sums up values of a vector, omits `NA` and returns `NA` if all values are `NA`.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'rather slow'? It takes about 5 - 10 times longer to generate a million random deviates `x <- rnorm(1000000)` than it does to apply `sumna(x)` and `sumna(x)` takes a few milliseconds, so I guess most of your computational time is in the simulations rather than this step?

Answer (score 10):

---

The `sum_` from `hablar` have the same behavior as the OP wanted.  So, no need to reinvent the wheel

```
library(hablar)
sum_(c(1:10, NA))
#[1] 55
sum_(c(NA, NA, NA))
#[1] NA
```

and it can be used in `tidyverse` or `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    summarise_all(sum_)
```

---

But, if we need to change the OP's custom function, instead of `ifelse`, a better option is `if/else`

```
sumna <- function(x) {
       if(all(is.na(x))) NA else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
   }
```

---

Also, we can use the vectorized `colSums`

```
v1 <- colSums(df1, na.rm = TRUE)
v1[colSums(is.na(df1)) == nrow(df1)] <- NA
```

---

As the dataset is huge, we can also make use of the efficient `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, sumna)]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
     summarise_all(sumna)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this is exactly what I need!

Comment: `sum_` is slow? `x = rnorm(1000000); microbenchmark(sumna(x), sum_(x))` for your `sumna()`?

Answer (score 6):

You can remove all NA's and test if the length is longer than 0.

```
sumna_a <- function(x) {
    x <- na.omit(x)
    if(length(x)) return(sum(x))
    NA
}

#or
sumna_b <- function(x) {
    if(length(na.omit(x))) return(sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
    NA
}
```

I think in most cases it should be efficient if you simply use `sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)` and test afterwards when `sum==0` if there are only `NA` like:

```
sumna_c <- function(x) {
    ret <- sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    if(ret == 0 && all(is.na(x))) {NA} else {ret}
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, please make this post [a wiki post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310947/community-wiki-where-is-it).

Comment: it's faster to use `x[!is.na(x)]` for simple vectors, rather than `na.omit()`.

Comment: @MartinMorgan On my PC and my R-Version `na.omit()` is faster than `x[!is.na(x)]`

Comment: Ah; try `y = rep(NA_real_, 1000000)`. Also I'm kind of unsure from the original question whether the concern is a million variables, or a million simulations each of a few variables.

Answer (score 4):

When comparing the posted methods it looks like [user10488504 function c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56474360/10488504) is currently most performant for cases when your sum is != 0 and you don't have only NA's. In case you have only NA's [Anti](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56473098/10488504), [RonakShah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56473216/10488504) and [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56473131/10488504) are good:

```
sumna_Anti <- function(x) {
  sumna <- NULL
  return(ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, sum(na.omit(x))))
}

sumna_RonakShah <- function(x) {
   c(NA, sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))[(sum(is.na(x)) != length(x)) +1]
}

sumna_akrun <- function(x) {
       if(all(is.na(x))) NA else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
   }

sumna_user10488504_a <- function(x) {
    x <- na.omit(x)
    if(length(x)) return(sum(x))
    NA
}

sumna_user10488504_b <- function(x) {
    if(length(na.omit(x))) return(sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
    NA
}

sumna_user10488504_c <- function(x) {
    ret <- sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    if(ret == 0 && all(is.na(x))) {NA} else {ret}
}

set.seed(0)
x <- rnorm(99999)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(sumna_Anti(x),
               sumna_RonakShah(x),
               sumna_akrun(x),
               sumna_user10488504_a(x),
               sumna_user10488504_b(x),
               sumna_user10488504_c(x)
               )

                    expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
           sumna_Anti(x) 307.288 310.0280 390.01838 319.2800 410.2040 2056.284   100    d
      sumna_RonakShah(x) 245.251 247.4715 269.40054 253.1650 259.7850  393.495   100  bc 
          sumna_akrun(x) 165.998 167.5005 209.39315 171.8925 190.8330 1768.761   100  b  
 sumna_user10488504_a(x) 221.275 222.6740 315.93037 229.0330 263.6405 1944.602   100   cd
 sumna_user10488504_b(x) 224.614 225.8170 261.77913 231.2305 234.6465 1934.120   100  bc 
 sumna_user10488504_c(x)  83.367  84.2610  86.16793  84.5900  86.4585  119.629   100 a   


x[sample(1:99999, 100)] <- NA
microbenchmark(sumna_Anti(x),
               sumna_RonakShah(x),
               sumna_akrun(x),
               sumna_user10488504_a(x),
               sumna_user10488504_b(x),
               sumna_user10488504_c(x)
               )

                    expr     min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval  cld
           sumna_Anti(x) 607.367 628.4000 907.53974 634.3195  692.0845 4205.011   100    d
      sumna_RonakShah(x) 246.992 251.1290 273.80595 254.6195  261.4470  455.446   100  b  
          sumna_akrun(x) 167.058 168.5790 196.13280 170.4125  186.2650  373.708   100 ab  
 sumna_user10488504_a(x) 517.615 539.2940 684.20267 543.6295  582.5330 2360.247   100   c 
 sumna_user10488504_b(x) 523.769 544.6195 869.76645 558.0240 1125.6725 3914.266   100    d
 sumna_user10488504_c(x)  84.142  85.2940  89.04266  86.4255   87.4020  207.624   100 a   

x = rep(NA_real_, 99999)
microbenchmark(sumna_Anti(x),
               sumna_RonakShah(x),
               sumna_akrun(x),
               sumna_user10488504_a(x),
               sumna_user10488504_b(x),
               sumna_user10488504_c(x)
               )

           sumna_Anti(x)  243.848  252.3825  308.2693  260.5285  286.8025  2198.275   100  a 
      sumna_RonakShah(x)  242.706  249.3855  287.1426  258.8390  278.5905  1882.114   100  a 
          sumna_akrun(x)  240.459  244.9125  269.2847  255.1230  274.9215   409.886   100  a 
 sumna_user10488504_a(x) 1241.069 1285.3075 1534.1261 1343.7185 1486.4220  3117.453   100  ab
 sumna_user10488504_b(x) 1244.580 1281.9825 2461.2302 1349.9840 1427.9640 97590.279   100   b
 sumna_user10488504_c(x)  320.084  323.1905  353.9885  340.3555  358.7490   478.537   100  a
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also subset values based on number of `NA`'s in `x`

```
sumna <- function(x) {
   c(NA, sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))[(sum(is.na(x)) != length(x)) +1]
}

sumna(c(1:10, NA))
#[1] 55
sumna(c(NA, NA, NA))
#[1] NA
sumna(1:5)
#[1] 15
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `colSums`. Assuming that you don't have a column with all 0s,

```
ifelse(colSums(abs(df), na.rm = TRUE) == 0, NA, colSums(df, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Could work. But in case that the some of numerical values will add up to 0 I'd have doubts to use it.