# R: Why does the sum of NAs returns zero

Tags: r

I was surprised to find out that `sum(rep(NA, 3), na.rm = TRUE)` returns `0` instead of `NA`. What is the logic behind this? Is there a way to force `sum`-like functions to return `NA` when all the inputs are `NA`s?

---

**Edit**
As pointed out by @Maël, I could just use `na.rm = FALSE`. The full story is I am applying `sum` to the rows of a matrix with missing values and I would like it to return the row sum while ignoring `NA`s, but it should return `NA` if all row values are `NA`s.

For instance, I would expect `rowSums(matrix(c(NA, NA, NA, 2), nrow = 2), na.rm = TRUE)` to return `c(NA, 2)` but it instead returns `c(0, 2)`. And if `na.rm = FALSE`, then it returns `c(NA, NA)`.

Comment: well, set `na.rm` to `FALSE`, or am I missing something?

Comment: What you do is just like `sum(numeric(0))`. Summing nothing up to get a zero is reasonable for me.

Comment: Otherwise, `function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA_integer_ else sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Partial dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371683/make-sum-of-an-empty-set-set-of-nas-na-instead-of-0

Comment: Seems like an exact dupe?  What's "partial" about it?

Comment: Because OP asking why on top of a possible solution, but yeah, that could be added as a duplicate

Comment: But "why" questions stray more towards "opinion-based".

Comment: But quick comment answer: if you remove the `NA`s from a all-`NA` vector, what is left? Nothing. What is the sum of nothing? 0. Makes sense to me. Note that `sum(NULL)` is also 0 so this seems to be consistent. (Also documented in `?sum`: *"For historical reasons, `NULL` is accepted and treated as if it were `integer(0)`."*)

Comment: Maybe use `replace` like: `M <- matrix(c(NA, NA, NA, 2), nrow = 2)` `replace(rowSums(M, na.rm = TRUE), rowSums(!is.na(M)) == 0, NA)`