# Use aggregate and keep NA rows

Tags: r

I have not spent such a time on one single task like this for years.

There are multiple hints here on SO for example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844613/na-values-and-r-aggregate-function) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737174/blend-of-na-omit-and-na-pass-using-aggregate) so one is tempted to say this is a duplicate (I would even say so). But with the examples and multiple trials I was not able to accomplish what's needed.

Here is full example:

```
x <- data.frame(idx=1:30, group=rep(letters[1:10],3), val=runif(30))

x$val[sample.int(nrow(x), 5)] <- NA; x
spl <- with(x, split(x, group))

lpp <- lapply(spl, 
          function(x) { r <- with(x, 
              data.frame(x, val_g=cut(val, seq(0,1,0.1), labels = FALSE),
                            val_g_lab=cut(val, seq(0,1,0.1)))); r })


rd <- do.call(rbind, lpp); ord <- rd[order(rd$idx, decreasing = FALSE), ]; ord

aggregate(val ~ group + val_g_lab, ord, 
          FUN=function(x) c(mean(x, na.rm = FALSE), 
                            sum(!is.na(x))), na.action=na.pass)
```

The desired ouput: I would like to have also the NA's included, after `aggregate()`. Currently the `aggregate()` drops the NA's rows.

```
      idx group        val val_g val_g_lab  
 a.1    1     a 0.53789249     6 (0.5,0.6]          
 b.2    2     b 0.01729695     1   (0,0.1]          
 c.3    3     c 0.62295270     7 (0.6,0.7]          
 d.4    4     d 0.60291892     7 (0.6,0.7]
 e.5    5     e 0.76422909     8 (0.7,0.8]
 f.6    6     f 0.87433547     9 (0.8,0.9]
 g.7    7     g         NA    NA      <NA>          
 h.8    8     h 0.50590159     6 (0.5,0.6]
 i.9    9     i 0.89084068     9 (0.8,0.9]
 ...... continue (full data set as @ord object.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work-around is simply not to use `NA` for the value groups. First, initialising your data as above:

```
x <- data.frame(idx=1:30, group=rep(letters[1:10],3), val=runif(30))

x$val[sample.int(nrow(x), 5)] <- NA; x
spl <- with(x, split(x, group))

lpp <- lapply(spl, 
      function(x) { r <- with(x, 
          data.frame(x, val_g=cut(val, seq(0,1,0.1), labels = FALSE),
                        val_g_lab=cut(val, seq(0,1,0.1)))); r })


rd <- do.call(rbind, lpp); 
ord <- rd[order(rd$idx, decreasing = FALSE), ];
```

Simply convert to character and covert NAs to some arbitrary string literal:

```
# Convert to character
ord$val_g_lab <- as.character(ord$val_g_lab)
# Convert NAs
ord$val_g_lab[is.na(ord$val_g_lab)] <- "Unknown"

aggregate(val ~ group + val_g_lab, ord, 
          FUN=function(x) c(mean(x, na.rm = FALSE), sum(!is.na(x))), 
          na.action=na.pass)
#   group val_g_lab      val.1      val.2
#1      e   (0,0.1] 0.02292533 1.00000000
#2      g (0.1,0.2] 0.16078353 1.00000000
#3      g (0.2,0.3] 0.20550228 1.00000000
#4      i (0.2,0.3] 0.26986665 1.00000000
#5      j (0.2,0.3] 0.23176149 1.00000000
#6      d (0.3,0.4] 0.39196441 1.00000000
#7      e (0.3,0.4] 0.39303518 1.00000000
#8      g (0.3,0.4] 0.35646994 1.00000000
#9      i (0.3,0.4] 0.35724889 1.00000000
#10     a (0.4,0.5] 0.48809261 1.00000000
#11     b (0.4,0.5] 0.40993166 1.00000000
#12     d (0.4,0.5] 0.42394859 1.00000000
# ...
#20     b   (0.9,1] 0.99562918 1.00000000
#21     c   (0.9,1] 0.92018049 1.00000000
#22     f   (0.9,1] 0.91379088 1.00000000
#23     h   (0.9,1] 0.93445802 1.00000000
#24     j   (0.9,1] 0.93325098 1.00000000
#25     b   Unknown         NA 0.00000000
#26     c   Unknown         NA 0.00000000
#27     d   Unknown         NA 0.00000000
#28     i   Unknown         NA 0.00000000
#29     j   Unknown         NA 0.00000000
```

Does this do what you want?

*Edit:*

To answer your question in the comments. Note `NaN` and `NA` are not quite the same (See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5686/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-na)). Note also that these two are very different from `"NaN"` and `"NA"`, which are string literals (i.e. just text).
But anyway, `NA`s  are special 'atomic' elements which are nearly always handled exceptionally by functions. So you have to look into the documentation how a particular function handles `NA`s. In this case, the `na.action` argument applies to the values that you aggregate over, not the 'classes' in your formula. The `drop=FALSE` argument could also be used, but then you get all combinations of the (in this case) two classifications. Redefining the `NA` to a string literal works because the new name is treated like any other class.

Comment: thanks, this is what's needed. But can you please explain why it does not work with NaN and this have to be replaced? If I rename the `Unknown` to `NaN` again, it works my way. Something with the class type?

Comment: (+1) Thanks, well, I'm aware of the difference of `NaN` and `NA` but somehow did not expect that the treatment of these are different within base `R` of `aggregate()` function. I still somehow expected this to be treated as another `level` factor on which I was wrong. Thanks.