# aggregate function in R, sum of NAs are 0

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr, summarize

I saw a list of questions asked in stack overflow, regarding the following, but never got a satisfactory answer. I will follow up on the following question [Blend of na.omit and na.pass using aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737174/blend-of-na-omit-and-na-pass-using-aggregate)

```
> test <- data.frame(name = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4),
  var1 = rep(c(1:3, NA), 3),
  var2 = 1:12,
  var3 = c(rep(NA, 4), 1:8))

> test
   name var1 var2 var3
1     A    1    1   NA
2     A    2    2   NA
3     A    3    3   NA
4     A   NA    4   NA
5     B    1    5    1
6     B    2    6    2
7     B    3    7    3
8     B   NA    8    4
9     C    1    9    5
10    C    2   10    6
11    C    3   11    7
12    C   NA   12    8
```

When I try out the given solution, instead of mean I try to find out the sum

```
aggregate(. ~ name, test, FUN = sum, na.action=na.pass, na.rm=TRUE)
```

the solution doesn't work as usual. Accordingly, it converts NA to 0, So the sum of NAs is 0. It displays it as 0 instead of NaN.

Why doesn't the following work for FUN=sum.And how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a lambda function with a condition to return `NaN` when `all` elements are `NA`

```
aggregate(. ~ name, test, FUN = function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NaN
     else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE), na.action=na.pass)
```

-output

```
  name var1 var2 var3
1    A    6   10  NaN
2    B    6   26   10
3    C    6   42   26
```

---

It is an expected behavior with `sum` and `na.rm = TRUE`.  According to `?sum`

> the sum of an empty set is zero, by definition.

```
> sum(c(NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0
```

Comment: I used the following 
aggregate(. ~ name, test, FUN = \(x) if(all(is.na(x))) {NaN} else {sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)}, na.action=na.pass).........why is it showing an error Error: unexpected input in "aggregate(. ~ name, test, FUN = \"

Comment: @okboi Probably you have an older `R` version..  then change the `\(x)` to `function(x)`