# How to use ddply to get weighted-mean of class in dataframe?

Tags: r, plyr, reshape, weighted-average, summarization

I'm new to plyr and want to take the weighted mean of values within a class to reshape a dataframe for multiple variables. Using the following code, I know how to do this for one variable, such as x2:

```
set.seed(123)
frame <- data.frame(class=sample(LETTERS[1:5], replace = TRUE),
                    x=rnorm(20), x2 = rnorm(20), weights=rnorm(20))
ddply(frame, .(class),function(x) data.frame(weighted.mean(x$x2, x$weights)))
```

However, I would like the code to create a new data frame for x and x2 (and any amount of variables in the frame). Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: (You know you have to assign the output of `ddply` to something, right?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might find what you want in the `?summarise` function. I can replicate your code with `summarise` as follows:

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(123)
frame <- data.frame(class=sample(LETTERS[1:5], replace = TRUE), x=rnorm(20), 
                    x2 = rnorm(20), weights=rnorm(20))
ddply(frame, .(class), summarise, 
      x2 = weighted.mean(x2, weights))
```

To do this for `x` as well, just add that line to be passed into the `summarise` function:

```
ddply(frame, .(class), summarise, 
      x = weighted.mean(x, weights),
      x2 = weighted.mean(x2, weights))
```

**Edit**: If you want to do an operation over many columns, use `colwise` or `numcolwise` instead of `summarise`, or do `summarise` on a `melt`ed data frame with the `reshape2` package, then `cast` back to original form. [Here's an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10787761/2596586)

---

That would give:

```
wmean.vars <- c("x", "x2")

ddply(frame, .(class), function(x)
      colwise(weighted.mean, w = x$weights)(x[wmean.vars]))
```

Finally, if you don't like having to specify `wmean.vars`, you can also do:

```
ddply(frame, .(class), function(x)
      numcolwise(weighted.mean, w = x$weights)(x[!colnames(x) %in% "weights"]))
```

which will compute a weighted-average for every numerical field, excluding the weights themselves.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is there a way to do this so you don't have to specify the function for each new variable? I'm working with a dataset with a 100 variables, so that would take a while!

Comment: Thanks @flodel for filling in my very terse explanation. Following @thelatemail below, one could use `wmean.vars <- setdiff(names(frame), c("class","weights"))` to avoid specifying `x` and `x2`.

Comment: well, thanks for mentioning `numcolwise`, I had never seen it before.

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` answer for fun, which also doesn't require specifying all the variables individually.

```
library(data.table)
frame <- as.data.table(frame)
keynames <- setdiff(names(frame),c("class","weights"))
frame[, lapply(.SD,weighted.mean,w=weights), by=class, .SDcols=keynames]
```

Result:

```
   class          x         x2
1:     B  0.1390808 -1.7605032
2:     D  1.3585759 -0.1493795
3:     C -0.6502627  0.2530720
4:     E  2.6657227 -3.7607866
```

Comment: +1 for `data.table`. Note that the `.SD` is unnecessary on `weights` (and there should be a workaround for `keynames` too, in theory): `frame[,lapply(.SD[,keynames,with=FALSE],weighted.mean,w=weights),by=class]` has the same result.