# Group By Row Value Difference

Tags: r, group-by

I have a table that has structure like: Year, Month, ValueA, ValueB, ValueC, etc.. I want to group the table by Year and Month, but aggregate based on the difference in column values.

```
Year Month ValueA ValueB ValueC
2016  1      40     53     49
2017  2      29     31     26
2016  1      25     20     31
2017  2      22     30     29
```

I want to output a table that looks like:

```
Year Month ValueA ValueB ValueC
2016  1      15     33     18
2017  2      7       1      3
```

How would I go about this? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use base R `aggregate` and group by `Year` and `Month` to calculate the difference between the two rows.

```
abs(aggregate(.~Year + Month, df, diff))

#  Year Month ValueA ValueB ValueC
#1 2016     1     15     33     18
#2 2017     2      7      1      3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Year = c(2016, 2017, 2016, 2017),
             Month = c(1, 2, 1, 2),
             ValueA = c(40, 29, 25, 22),
             ValueB = c(53, 31, 20, 30),
             ValueC = c(49, 26, 31, 29))

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarize(ValueA = abs(diff(ValueA)), ValueB = abs(diff(ValueB)), ValueC = abs(diff(ValueC)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use approach described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787640/ddply-summarize-for-repeating-same-statistical-function-across-large-number-of) using `plyr`:

```
ddply(df, .(Year, Month), numcolwise(diff))
```